# Регулярные выражения. Поиск текста ссылки vk и замена на текст ссылку discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

мне нужен поиск текст-ссылок из [vk](https://vk.com) и замена на discord текст-ссылку

```
import re

txt = "Какой-нибудь текст [https://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст"
x = re.search("^https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|[a-zA-zа-яА-я]$", txt)
print(x)
```

Comment: Результат из примера какой хотите получить? Вот такой подойдет? https://regex101.com/r/cpj3xM/1

Comment: Вполне, только я хочу заменить текст из txt, то есть вот такой результат: "Какой-нибудь текст [удалят три способности](https://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981) какой-нибудь текст"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу то что-то такое должно получится

```py
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote

links = [
    'Какой-нибудь текст [https://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
    'Какой-нибудь текст [http://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
    'Какой-нибудь текст [http://www.vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
    'Какой-нибудь текст [https://www.vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
]


pat = re.compile(r'\[(http.*?)]')

def convert_to_normal(item: str):
    link, text = item.split('|')

    return f'[{link}]({text})'

def fetch_link_n_header(item: str):
    return pat.sub(lambda x: convert_to_normal(x.group(1)), unquote(item))


print(
    *map(fetch_link_n_header, links),
    sep='\n'
)
# Какой-нибудь текст [https://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981](удалят три способности) какой-нибудь текст
# Какой-нибудь текст [http://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981](удалят три способности) какой-нибудь текст
# Какой-нибудь текст [http://www.vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981](удалят три способности) какой-нибудь текст
# Какой-нибудь текст [https://www.vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981](удалят три способности) какой-нибудь текст
```

### UPD:

#### Немного упростил:

```py
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote

links = [
    'Какой-нибудь текст [https://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
    'Какой-нибудь текст [http://vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
    'Какой-нибудь текст [http://www.vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
    'Какой-нибудь текст [https://www.vk.com/wall-80197218_1416981%7Cудалят три способности] какой-нибудь текст',
]

pat = re.compile(r'\[(http.*?)\|(.*?)]')

def format_link(item: str):
    return pat.sub(r'[\1](\2)', unquote(item))

print(
    *map(format_link, links),
    sep='\n'
)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @RAINGM, немного упростил. глянте